# php loop through results without using the native driver

Tags: php

I need to rewrite my php code so that it does not use the native driver php5-mysqlnd.

On my development machine my code works fine because I have php5-mysqlnd installed, but as soon as I installed php5-mysqlnd on my VPS host then apache failed and wouldn't start.  And so I needed to have everything wiped and a fresh server install.  It's something to do with Plesk, I don't care about those details I know I can't use php5-mysqlnd so I just need my php to work without it.

So I don't care that everyone says it is the wrong technology and I don't care if people say it's an old technology.

The code below works on my development machine and I need to rewrite it without the native driver, how do I do that?

```
$db = new mysqli($_SESSION["DB_HOST"], $_SESSION["DB_USERNAME"], $_SESSION["DB_PASSWORD"], $_SESSION["DB_DATABASE_NAME"]) or die('Cannot connect');

$stmt = $db->prepare("call get_languages( ? )");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $iLanguageId );
$stmt->execute();

if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    { echo "<p>" . $row['language'] . "</p>"; }
    $result->free_result();
}
else
{ echo '<h2>Error: No languages listed.</h2>'; }
```

Comment: Indeed, this was a [bug](https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6009360-mysqlnd-support-for-plesk-11-5) in plesk but since then been solved quite a while. Sounds very naive what you're trying to do here, so don't be scared for all the down votes. It seems like you don't care about all the problems you're having using the php's sql native driver and the disadvantages you will have to face for not using it. 70% of all the MySQL/PHP tutorials found on google contain the original MySQL API .. are you having problems finding time to read that too?

Comment: I've found a lot of tutorials but everyone of them uses the native driver.  There might be a tutorial out there somewhere which will work without it, if you know it then please just add the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could uninstall php5-mysqlnd switch back to libmysqlclient if that's what you want.

Another option is to use the PDO driver and rewrite your code to use PDO instead.

Comment: One problem is that some commands won't work.

    $result->fetch_assoc()

I think this command is the one I was having problems with because it's limited to the native driver, so how do I loop through the results set without it.

Comment: Then you should either sort out the Plesk issue (which has been resolved?) or switch your code to using the PDO library (along with the PDO driver).

Comment: You might also want to checkout [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#113398) on php.net.